# Sas: How to use macro for infile multiple txt?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I need the macro to have one parameter which is the path of the text files.

This is what I have now. I have 6 txt with name= NY2012.txt   NY2013.txt   NY2014.txt.....etc.

```
    %macro data ;

    %let list= 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017;


    data allData;
    delete;  (what should I put here?)
    run;


    %do i=1 %to 6;
    %let currItem = %scan(&list, &i);

    filename f&list "/folders/myfolders/NY&list.txt"; (should this be here?)
    data currentData;
    x = &currItem;

    infile f&list  truncover;
    input value $ 1-20;
    retain year;
    if _n_=1 then year=year_1;

    run;

    * Keeping adding things to the cumulative data set;
    data allData;
    set allData currentData;
    run;
    %end;

    %mend data;

    %data;
```

Then I should end up with a dataset for each year and one large dataset that included all the years. How should I fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should make loop by elements in macro variable and work with scanned element of list but not with list of elements inside the loop. So the code will look like:

```
%let list=2017 2018 2019;

%macro data(tlist) ; %macro d; %mend d;

    %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&tlist,%str( )));
    %let currItem = %scan(&tlist, &i, %str( ));

    filename f&currItem. "/folders/myfolders/NY&currItem..txt";
    data currentData&currItem;
    x = &currItem;

    infile f&currItem  truncover;
    input value $ 1-20;
    retain year;
    if _n_=1 then year=year_1;

    run;

    * Keeping adding things to the cumulative data set;
    data allData;
    set allData currentData&currItem;
    run;
    filename f&currItem. clear;
    %end;

%mend data;

%data;

%data(&list);
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple wildcard on the infile will suffice.

In this case `????` means any 4 characters. You could also use `NY*.txt`.

```
data allData ;
  length _f f $256. ; /* temporary & permanent variables to hold the filename being read */
  infile "/folders/myfolders/NY????.txt" truncover filename=_f ;
  input value $ 1-20 ;
  f = _f ;
  /* derive the year from the filename */
  /* compress(var,,'kd') means Keep Digits */
  year = input(compress(scan(f,-1,'/'),,'kd'),8.) ;
run ;
```